# Could Spark direct streaming job be able to automatically reassign its consumers when new Kafka brokers added and partitions reassigned

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to add new nodes to Kafka cluster. And I will do the reassignment of the topics. But in the mean time, some Spark Kafka direct streaming jobs are running in the cluster. 
If I added new brokers to Kafka and reassigned the partitions of topics, will the Kafka direct consuming job on Spark be able to reassign the executors and consumers to adapt the reassignment?

Comment: Yes, it will be able to adjust to the new partition assignment.

Comment: But the job just knows the old brokers configured at the start. How could the job know new brokers and new partition reassignments? Could the old brokers tell it all the information?

Comment: Kafka has an internal protocol which whispers new brokers as they're joined in the cluster. That is why it suffices to supply your application a single Kafka Broker and it'll know automatically all the brokers in the cluster.

Comment: OK, I'll give a try. Thank you for your answers.